# WSAECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer Netweaver

Tags: abap, sap-gui

I have a question. I'm doing a tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_YiSdk0jXA&t=813s

I can not connect through SAPGUI 750 to the machine. I still have the error
"connection to partner '127.0.0.1' broken
WSAECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer "
What should I do to get a connection? Or maybe you have other ideas on how to start learning SAP ABAP? Is there an emulator?

Comment: So, you also installed the ABAP server 7.50, and you started it, right? The error you have is when you try to connect to it through the client application (SAP GUI), but there's no reply.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities here as the message is generic for not able to establish a connection,

After of course as Sandra mentioned verifying the instance as actually up and running.

- Check your port forwarding rules that they are correct.
- Check your sapgui settings, typically the instance number is what I see being wrong the most.

Good luck.